# How to get checkbox inside select options

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to get checkboxes inside select options. It seems selection option cannot have checkboxes. What is the other way around may be using simple HTML elements? I need to be able to multi-select options from a dropdown.I needed to make it work like multi-select. Not able to get the look and feel like multiselct.

```
<dl class="dropdown"> 

    <dt>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="hida">Select</span>    
      <p class="multiSel"></p>  
    </a>
    </dt>

    <dd>
        <div class="mutliSelect">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="one" />one</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="two" />two</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="three" />three</li>
                <li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Javascript

```
var ahead = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var selectdd = document.getElementsByTagName('dd');
var anySelect = document.querySelectorAll('.mutliSelect input');
var selectedStore = [];
console.log(ahead);
console.log(anySelect);

var cb = function(e){
console.log(e);
console.log(selectdd);
selectdd[0].style.display = 'block';
}

var selectCb = function(e){
var selectedVal = e.target.value;
debugger
selectedStore.push(selectedVal);
}

function addEventListenerList(list, event, fn) {
    for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
        list[i].addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    }
}

ahead[0].addEventListener('click',cb);
addEventListenerList(anySelect, 'click', selectCb);


console.log("Store status = ",selectedStore);
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Are you trying to put checkboxes inside the ```select multiple```? Why would you even want to do that? Sounds redundant

Answer (score 0):

Select options cannot contain checkboxes, check the HTML specification for what is valid and what is not.
See: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-option-element

Comment: Not sure why you're getting downvoted. It's true. Nothing to do with React, just basic HTML. Which feels a bit like learning to run before you can walk

Comment: Matt, yep, totally. Sadly too many people can't be bothered to learn HTML. As for downvoting, such is the Stack Overflow community these days.

Comment: I don't understand why people are downvoting. I don't see any problem with the question. If this is all about learning only why do we have StackOverflow. As long as the business validations of StackOverflow are allowing a question there is no reason why there should be a race downvote.